# When should I use a Webform vs Fields API in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am preparing a site that will track a group of 400+ participants in a set of trainings that will occur over several years. Every few months they will be asked to fill in some forms tracking their progress. We would like to be able to get some basic stats and to export this data. It would be nice if they could enter data over several sessions since they are asked to write longer answers.

Is Webforms an option here? It looks like it is good for simple forms, but ours will be quite long and we will ask them to log in already anyway. I was about to create a different Content Type for each time of form, and get them to create a new node for each form that they fill in.

What are your thoughts and experiences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be a lot easier to go the way you are leaning toward, by creating different content types. If you have a *lot* of different types of forms then that might be the only road block.

The good thing about going with having them create the nodes is that it should be very easy for you to run reports on the nodes in the future, export spreadsheets, etc (using views).

The one problem with this approach would be that you eventually want those forms to be "finalized" (they are no longer able to edit after a certain point). Take a look at this thread for doing something with [Rules and Content Access](http://drupal.org/node/357786) (may have to modify the approach for Drupal 7 a bit).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the "finalized" problem - it had occurred to me but didn't think to add it to the question

Answer (score 1):

If your forms are long you can break them up with the [Multistep](http://drupal.org/project/multistep) module. For allowing smoother input between sessions there exists a [patch](http://drupal.org/node/645388) that allows each step to be saved.